# Not getting status message from Receipt Printer for "Receipt Empty" case

Tags: c#, .net, epson, opos, pos-for-.net

I am using a TM U220 receipt printer . And i am using Epson OPOS ADK for .Net and Microsoft PosFor.Net for the developement of my receipt printing application.

I am trying to get the status information from the device like Receipt empty and receipt near empty. But i am always getting the status as success, even if there is no receipt present in the printer.

```
PosPrinter m_Printer; // Name of printer instance.
//Initialisation of printer.
//

m_Printer.Open();
m_Printer.Claim();
m_Printer.Enabled = true;

if(m_Printer.RecEmpty || m_Printer.RecNearEmpty)
{
//Show the status message.
}
```

The above code was used for testing this situation. I am always getting those bool values as false irrespective of the receipt condition in the printer.

Please help me on this. Whether i should do any more action for getting those status information.POS

Comment: Have you tried testing `CapRecEmptySensor` to make sure the printer/ opos driver supports the `RecEmpty` method? From the docs "If the CapRecEmptySensor property is set to false, the value of RecEmpty is always set to false."

Comment: CapRecEmptySensor value is getting as true only . I checked that too.

Comment: I have just checked this with a TM-T88 and I can get this to happen under the following situations (1) The call to open/claim fails (also results in not been able to print) or (2) The paper cover is open, as it would appear that if the cover is open `RecEmpty` always returns false, hopefully that helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

try adding event handlers for the m_printer object. And put a try catch over this block, so that you can be notified of what is happening!

Answer (score 0):

Epson OPOS changed this, even in its latest version (2.80). 
For the TM-U220 model I use the following:

Enable the PowerNotify

```
m_Printer.PowerNotify = 1
```

Then get the printer Powerstate

```
Select Case m_Printer.PowerState
    Case 2000       'DESCONOCIDO, NO TIENE LA CAPACIDAD, NO HACER NADA
    Case 2001       'EN LINEA
    Case 2002, 2003, 2004    'APAGADA 'FUERA DE LINEA 'APAGADA
    msgbox "check printer"
End Select
```

This does not work with the TM-U950 model.

Comment: Ideally this should be a C# code snippet since that is what the question calls for.